# Use of a possessive adjective for a permit

Tags: déterminants, possessif

In the sentence “Grégoire est content parce qu'il a son permis de conduire maintenant.”, would you use the word *son*? If not which article would you use, if at all?

Comment: Please ask unrelated questions in different posts. Moreover your second question was quite unclear. Please add more details about conditions for which you believe that the use of a time indicator is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. In your first example, one would use *son* as it's the right possessive determiner (*son* is for *permis de conduire* which is masculine singular).

On your second question, that's correct as well: it's totally ok to use the indicator of time in this case. It just adds more precision.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, both *son* and *le* would be correct :

> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a *son* permis de conduire maintenant.
>
> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a *le* permis de conduire maintenant.

Even if you use *le*, the meaning of the sentence implies that it is Grégoire's one, it would be absurd if it was the driving licence of another person. And it is the same for the second sentence :

> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a eu *son* permis de conduire hier.
>
> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a eu *le* permis de conduire hier.

Answer (score 1):

Both

> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a son permis de conduire maintenant.

and

> Grégoire est content parce qu'il a le permis de conduire maintenant.

are correct if you are speaking about the fact that he passed the exam.  If you are speaking about the paper proving the fact that he passed the exam, you'll use only "son". ("Grégoire est venu en bus, il n'a pas **le** permis ?  — Si, mais arrivé à l'aéroport il s'est rendu compte qu'il avait oublié **son** permis chez lui et n'a pas pu louer de voiture.")